# Libraries not visible to modules after SBT import in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Project compiles and runs fine, but the sources can't see the libraries within the IDE.

[image: screenshot]

Note in the middle, the editor doesn't recognize imports from libraries or other modules in the project, although you can see the libraries on the left.

I have a feeling this is due to my lack of understanding of how the modules system works. I started with just the sources and build.sbt, and used `File > New > Project from Existing Sources` in IntelliJ (latest version 15.0.5). IntelliJ created separate modules for the project, build, `main` and `test`. It seems `main` and `test` don't have access to the dependencies.

I check out the Project Structure, and sure enough, the dependencies are there for the top level "tcparser" module, but not for "main" or "test":

[image]

So I hit the green `+` on the right and try to add the library dependencies for the `test` module, but I get the error message `Module "tcparser" must not contain source root "path to \src\main\java". The root already belongs to module "main"`, which makes no sense to me.

[image]

What is going on and how do I fix? I didn't particularly want to split my project into modules, so I'm fine getting rid of them if that's the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opening the project in IntelliJ for the first time, you need to select the `build.sbt` file, not the top level folder. It should then be imported correctly, without separate "modules" for main and test.

[image]